# Receiving the capabilities of a WMTS Server

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to get the capabilities of a WMTS Server according to this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html

The GetCapabilities response looks like this: https://pastebin.com/RRVmX9Ms

With the following code I get no result, no error or warning (console remains empty):

```
var parser = new ol.format.WMTSCapabilities();

fetch('WMTSCapabilities.xml').then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(text) {

          var result = parser.read(text);
          var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result, {
              layer: 'DOP_20_C',
              matrixSet: 'ADV_25832_Quad'
          });

        console.log(options);
 });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Openlayers can only use projections EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 whereas your WMTS use EPSG:25832.

As you don't provide the projection code and don't use proj4js (the JavaScript library to manage projections required for projections different than EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326), it fails in function `ol.proj.getTransformFromProjections` of the library.

You need to add just after `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>` the following

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.4.4/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://epsg.io/4258.js"></script>
<script src="https://epsg.io/31467.js"></script>
<script src="https://epsg.io/25832.js"></script>
```

and register the proj4 function with

```
  ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

within your `<script>` block

You can see [a demo in action](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/58a6b2d8160cd50995941f6ff68aeeab) to illustrate

PS: I call every EPSG codes your WMTS provides to avoid the same issue with other projections.

Comment: Thank you! The options are returned now. However, the WMTS layer is not located properly yet: https://i.imgur.com/jCZJTOW.png. But I'll open another question for that...